# get rid of optional when printing badge

Tags: ios, swift3

```
let vals2: String? = String(describing: store?.data?.newsArticles?.count)
print(vals2!)
self.newsTabBarItem.badgeValue = vals2!
self.menuList = (store?.data?.newsArticles)!
```

I am getting the count of `array` and putting it as `badge` value, however its  showing in badge Optional(5 for ex. how can this be solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
store?.data?.newsArticles?.count
```

is an `optional`, then

```
String(describing: store?.data?.newsArticles?.count)
```

will be equal to `"Optional(3)"`and it's type will be `String` not `String?`. You need to unwrap `count` instead of `vals2` :

```
let newsArticles = store?.data?.newsArticles // newsArticles is an Optional
let vals2: String = String(describing: newsArticles!.count)
print(vals2)
self.newsTabBarItem.badgeValue = vals2
self.menuList = newsArticles!
```

Even better, if your code requires `newsArticles` :

```
if let newsArticles = store?.data?.newsArticles { // newsArticles won't be an Optional
    let vals2 = String(describing: newsArticles.count)
    print(vals2)
    self.newsTabBarItem.badgeValue = vals2
    self.menuList = newsArticles
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get your `Optional(n)` in that call:

```
String(describing: store?.data?.newsArticles?.count)
```

Because you're asking for description of `Optional<Int>`.

You may try this:

```
let vals2: String? = store?.data?.newsArticles?.count.map { count in
    String(describing: count)
}
self.newsTabBarItem.badgeValue = vals2 // don't use `!` here
```

Comment: i got an error on map, value of type int have no member map

Comment: Can you take screenshot of your code(part with map) with error? And check that there's no `?` after `count`: `.count.map`, not `.count?.map`.